# How to understand the result of disassembling IDA Pro (dll x86_64)

Tags: ida, disassemblers

I'm studying the dll that was built for x86_64.

I study where there are links to the function "call_f1_1806F3630" and do not understand three of them. Are these features of OOP? Help me figure it out:
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/crsvYi4QLBE6dQ

1. Is this a virtual table with methods of some class?

```
.rdata:0000000180B8E730 BC 06 03 80 01 00 00 00       off_180B8E730   dq offset sub_1800306BC ; DATA XREF: sub_180016668+28↑o
.rdata:0000000180B8E730                                                                       ; sub_180169E2C+2E↑o ...
.rdata:0000000180B8E738 44 8D 03 80 01 00 00 00                       dq offset sub_180038D44
.rdata:0000000180B8E740 F0 8D 03 80 01 00 00 00                       dq offset sub_180038DF0
...
.rdata:0000000180B8E800 30 03 6F 80 01 00 00 00                       dq offset sub_1806F0330
.rdata:0000000180B8E808 30 36 6F 80 01 00 00 00                       [B]dq offset call_f1_1806F3630[/B]
.rdata:0000000180B8E810 20 3D 6F 80 01 00 00 00                       dq offset sub_1806F3D20
.rdata:0000000180B8E818 60 99 16 80 01 00 00 00                       dq offset sub_180169960
```

2. This is not clear at all.

```
.rdata:0000000180EDAE60 30 36 6F 00 FF FF FF FF       stru_180EDAE60  IPtoStateMap <rva call_f1_1806F3630, -1>
.rdata:0000000180EDAE60                                                                       ; DATA XREF: .rdata:stru_180EDAE28↑o
.rdata:0000000180EDAE68 6B 36 6F 00 00 00 00 00                       IPtoStateMap <rva loc_1806F366B, 0>
.rdata:0000000180EDAE70 C4 37 6F 00 FF FF FF FF                       IPtoStateMap <rva loc_1806F37C4, -1>
.rdata:0000000180EDAE78 CB 37 6F 00 00 00 00 00                       IPtoStateMap <rva loc_1806F37CB, 0>
.rdata:0000000180EDAE80 71 93 AE 00 01 00 00 00                       IPtoStateMap <rva sub_180AE9371, 1>
.rdata:0000000180EDAE88 80 93 AE 00 00 00 00 00                       IPtoStateMap <rva loc_180AE9380, 0>
```

3. This is not clear at all.

```
.pdata:000000018110D94C 30 36 6F 00 DA 37 6F 00 88 1C+                RUNTIME_FUNCTION <rva call_f1_1806F3630, rva algn_1806F37DA, \
.pdata:000000018110D94C D0 00                                                           rva stru_180D01C88>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is a function pointer in a virtual function table. The second two are [x64 exception metadata included by the compiler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64?view=msvc-160).